# How do I normalize my backpropagation neural network with multiple feature with multiple range?

Tags: neural-network, normalization, backpropagation

I have a data set with 11 feature with following range:

```
1000001 < feature 1  < 1560504
10000 < feature 2  < 15151
1 < feature 3  < 8
1001 < feature 4  < 3051
100 < feature 5  <  136
100 < feature 6  <  323
1 < feature 7  < 179
0 < feature 8  <  23
0 < feature 9  <  60034
114206 < feature 10  < 5318251
30 < feature 11  < 356
```

and one *boolean* output.

I want to use a backpropagation neural network for this dataset.
How do I normalize my input?

Answer (score 1):

Each feature can be normalised independently.

```
   x_i = (x_i - mean(x))/sigma(x) where x is a feature
```

Further, you would be required to store mean and sigma for each feature and use the same on test/new data before prediction.

If you are using Scikit etc., you can use standard preprocessing packages:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

Comment: thanks a lot. i use matlab and according to your result I use zscore(trainData). It apply Standardized z-score normalization for each column. but there is negative values in my normalized data set . is it ok?

Comment: Negative values are OK (is you use signoid or tanh as activation function, the range extends also in the negative domain). I not use z-score because it suppose a normal distribution of your features and that could not be true. Better, imho, linear normalization between [0,1] or [-1, 1]. For output, normalize linearly in the range of output of the activation function, avoiding the asymptotic part where there is a minor resolution and the net performances are worse: [-0.9, 0.9] for tanh or [0, 0.9] for sigmoid function.